# How do I export an JSON file correctlly react?

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, fetch

I have an API url where I will do a get request. But I dont want to use this directly from my component. I want to store the result into an json file and import it from my component.

example of psedocode:

```
// example.json
let data = fetch(url).then()

export data
```

```
// Buy.jsx
import data from './data/example.json

useEffect(
//... store it to the state
)
```

What is the correct way to implement this ?

Comment: A react app running in a browser cannot write files. Two ways would be to call the API at runtime or get the data and write it out at or before compile time to be able to `import` it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of json u can do like this

```
const movies_data = {
"data": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "title": "Freed"
        },
        {
              "id": 2,
              "title": "Fifty"
        }
        ]
    }
export default movies_data;
```

and then can import where u want

Comment: This is one way, another way is no need to export the JSON file. just keep it plain JSON file and when importing it import it using a alias and use it. 

e.g. import movies_data from 'your_path_to_json_file'

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code snippet will cover all the needs:

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {

    const fetchData = async() => {
      const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

      //whatever you receive convert to the JSON format ('axios' does this by default)
      const data = await result.json();
      // console.log('data: ', data);
      setPosts(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
    {posts.map(
        post => (
          <React.Fragment key={post.id}>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      )
    }
</div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

### Explanation:

This example utilize [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) a built-in JavaScript solution for querying REST API's from any source. Once you receive the result from the API fetch will convert it to the JSON format. Following step is saving the outcome using `setPosts(data)` method defined at the beginning of the component.

References:

- [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#:%7E:text=Keyed%20Fragments.%20Fragments%20declared%20with%20the%20explicit%20%3CReact.Fragment%3E,only%20attribute%20that%20can%20be%20passed%20to%20Fragment.)
- [React Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html)

Feel free to ask any questions regarding this code.